# Is it possible to set dimensions for UIImagePickerController's editor?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to make users choose a photo from their library and crop this photo to specific dimensions like a circular , 80 x 60 sized photo.

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func choosePhoto(_ sender: Any) {

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
    self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let choosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    imageView.image = choosenImage
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I pick photos using this code but edit screen is a rectangle so it is not what i'm looking for.Is it possible to change the edit screen's dimensions ?

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't have any circular crop feature by default. You will need to integrate external library for implementing crop feature.

You can make use of these for circular cropping https://github.com/kekearif/KACircleCropViewController https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController